# How to automatically resolve merge conflicts by selecting the remote version in Git?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

Is there any way to specify to git to automatically resolve the conflicts for a pack of files by taking the remote version for each of them? For instance, to take the remote version of each files in a certain directory?

Comment: See SO answer **[git command for making one branch like another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267)** for *all* the current possible ways to **simulate `git merge -s their`**.

Answer (score 19):

[git-merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) seems to support only the "ours" strategy, where the result of a merge is the local version. And that only for the whole tree.

If you enter a conflicted state while doing a merge, you can use [git-checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)'s `--theirs` with a path to retrieve files from the index.

Finally you can [git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to force parts of the tree to a specific commit.

There's now also http://www.seanius.net/blog/2011/02/git-merge-s-theirs/ who basically recommends making a `merge -s ours` and then reverse-apply the changes.

Comment: 10x David for the tip. It seems that git-checkout does the trick. Unfortunately, the --ours|--theirs options are not supported by my version of git :( seems like I have to do some updating...

Comment: If there is no --ours|--theirs option to git-checkout, you can use 'git show :2:full_path > file' for --ours (stage #2), and 'git show :3:full_path > file' for --theirs (stage #3). Or use 'git checkout-index --stage=2|3 -- file...' plumbing

Answer (score 7):

You can use `recursive` strategy (-s) with `theirs` option (-X). That is:

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs source_branch
```