# Git: merge master to new branch and clear out master

Tags: git

I was wondering if somebody could explain to me how to GIT merge master into a new branch and then clear out master as to have master clean working directory.

In other words: master -> PHP since master will now have Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be, if nobody has cloned your repo yet, to:

- make a `PHP` branch where master currently is
- reset master to the `Python` tip

See:

```
git checkout master
git branch PHP
git checkout Python
git checkout -B master Python
```

From the [`checkout` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]
```

> This form switches branches by updating the index, working tree, and `HEAD` to reflect the specified branch or commit.
>
> If `-B` is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset.
>
> This is the transactional equivalent of

```
$ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
$ git checkout <branch>
```

---

But if others have cloned your repo, you need to reset the content of master, keeping all the previous commits.

That would be a good case for the non-existent `merge -s theirs` (where your discard your current content and replace it with the one of another branch, like `Python` in tour case):

See "[git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267)" for more.
(and start first by making the `PHP` branch where `master` currently is, like above: that bit doesn't change and will mark where `PHP` updates need to go from now on)

Answer (score 1):

"master" is just a name. It's the default, but there's nothing magical about it.

You could rename your current "master" branch to "PHP" with `git branch -m master PHP`

Then checkout whatever historic commit you're calling "clean" (use `git log` to figure that out), and then `git branch master` to create a master branch at that point.