# Git, must pull, know there will be conflicts, but local version is irrelevant

Tags: git, command-line, merge, repository, conflict

I know that upon pulling there will be conflicts, but I already know that the repository version is better. How do I resolve all conflicts on the command line with a git command

something like  `$> git resolve conflict with theirs` or something

Comment: You could use one of the merge "theirs" strategies after fetching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to keep your changes then pull is the wrong action. If the repository version is unequivocally better you can just fetch and reset.

E.g.

```
git fetch

# Assuming my branch was based on origin/master,
# throw my changes away.
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Obviously be careful with this, as you may lose uncommitted changes. You may want to do a plain `git reset origin/master` and remove your local changes carefully by hand.

Comment: thanks for explaining fetch, this may be the right track for me!

Answer (score 3):

Can you still merge your HEAD with remote without totally removing your changes, but always resolving conflicts in remote's favor:

```
git pull -s recursive -Xtheirs <remote-ref>
```

But beware — your changes will be *partially* saved, and *partially* overwritten. This may be OK if you expect them overwritten in one part of tree and kept in another, but be very careful with the resulting code, be sure to review it and compare it to the remote version.

Answer (score 3):

By specifying the merge strategy you should be able to do this:

```
git fetch
git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs remotes/origin/branch_name
```

or

```
git pull -s recursive -Xtheirs origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
git clean
git pull
```

if not helped, then try

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```