# How do I make my branch like another branch while making the changes as a single commit?

Tags: git, git-branch

Suppose I have a `master` branch and a `feature` branch. `feature` is severely outdated and I now want to make it exactly like `master`, but I want all changes made to `feature` that were required in order to complete the "merge" to appear in a single commit.

First I tried this:

```
git checkout feature
git merge --squash master
```

But this gives me a squillion conflicts. I don't want to manually resolve conflicts, I want to simply take whatever is in `master` and be done with it. So I do this:

```
git checkout feature
git merge --squash -X theirs master
```

With this I still get merge conflicts (where files were deleted in `master`. What do I do now? I could do `git reset --hard master` but then I don't get a commit message that shows the changes.

Any ideas? I'm using `git 1.8.1.2`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by _"but I want all changes made to feature to appear in a single commit"_? Do you want to keep or discard the work currently in `feature`?

Comment: @200_success I mean that I would like all the changes that had to be made in order to make `feature` like `master` to appear in a single commit, like with a `merge --squash`.

Comment: The important question is *why* do you want it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git command for making one branch like another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another)

Comment: The thing is, you are dropping the changes you made on feature so far and starting again with content of master. So just drop the commits too (`git reset --hard master`); they are not contributing to the project anyway.

Comment: @JanHudec say you've got a branch *formatting changes* where you want to do only changes related to formatting.

Comment: @Arman: That does not explain why you want to keep the history that didn't contribute to the project in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answers to [git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4911794/1256452).  Note that there's rarely any good reason to do this in the first place (as already noted as the first comment on that question).

There's another method for doing this, not listed there.  This assumes you're in the top level directory of your repository:

```
git checkout feature
git merge --no-commit -s ours master # -s ours just to make things quiet
git rm -q -rf .           # remove all resulting files
git checkout master -- .  # replace with master branch version
git commit
```

In fact, you don't need the `git merge` command at all; here's a variant without it:

```
git checkout feature
git rm -q -rf .; git checkout master -- .
git rev-parse master > .git/MERGE_HEAD
git commit
```

(the difference is that the last `git commit` will give you a different starting message—using `git merge --no-commit` leaves a `MERGE_MSG` file in the git directory as well, to provide the commit message).