# Git workflow: How to avoid this kind of merge conflict

Tags: git, git-workflow

I have two branches: `qa` and `prd`. Initially they are completely the same (`qa` is based on `prd`).

Step 1: A creates a feature branch `f1` from `prd`. A completes development.

Step 2: A merges `f1` into `qa` for testing. Done.

Step 3: A merges `f1` into `prd`.

Now I want to make `qa` and `prd` equal again (they seem to be equal from human's perspective but git refuses to recognize as equal because the two merges are separate, this is one thing I think git doesn't really fit our purpose), so:

Step 4: A merges `prd` into `qa`.

Step 5: A creates a second feature branch `f2` from `prd`. A completes development.

Step 6: A tries to merge `f2` into `qa` but sees a conflict.

**Question: I would like to avoid the conflict in Step 6.** I have other restrictions:

- I cannot promote changes by merging `qa` into `prd`;
- I cannot use cherry pick;
- I can accept any answer that can be automated through GitHub Action
- I must preserve history of `qa` (is it even possible?)

All these restrictions might sound strange to you but it is out of my ability to change them.

I did a bit of research and looks like a hard reset of `qa` to `prd` makes them TRULY equal (in git's perspective) , but this loses all history of `qa`. Is there any way to force git to think that they are equal without losing history? Again I'm beginning to think that git doesn't really fit our purposes and I'm trying to shoe-hone it.

There is also a post that looks to be helpful but I'm not 100% sure:
[Making two branches identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320517/making-two-branches-identical)

Comment: I believe you should not merge `f1` into `prd` directly, but rather merge `qa` into `prd`.

Comment: Hi @PeterKrebs thanks, yeah I understand that will prevent the conflict from occuring. However, I cannot do that because `qa` is a volatile sandbox branch. We actually don't do any test in `qa` so maybe `sandbox` is a better name.

Comment: In that case I would treat `qa` as a second class citizen and force-push to it, simply overwriting it? It's more like `qa` is there because you don't have a pipeline set up.