# Force merge branch from specific commit

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a branch "mybranch" which was created from the master but it has not been updated for the last couple of months. I want to update "mybarch" from a specific commit of the master branch. I want to ignore anything additional which is in "mybarch" and keep it in sync with the specific commit of the master branch. How can I achieve this? I'm trying this, does this sound ok? This results into many conflicts whereas I want to accept what comes from the master.

```
git checkout mybranch
git merge --squash master <commit-id>
```

Comment: If the history of the branch doesn't matter you can `git checkout -B mybranch <commit-id>`

Comment: @Opal This will create new branch if I'm not wrong but I want to update the existing branch

Comment: Yes, it will ;) That's why I mentioned history not being relevant. What about: `git merge --squash -X theirs <commit-id>..<master-head>`

Comment: @Opal Tried this but there seems to be another problem which I didn't notice earlier - suppose master has A+B and mybranch has A+C,  after merge I will be getting A+B+C where I want mybranch is same as master which is A+B

Answer (score 0):

> suppose `master` has `A+B` and `mybranch` has `A+C`, after merge I will be getting `A+B+C` where I want `mybranch` is same as `master` which is `A+B`

Then you can simulate the merge with one [of the `--theirs` strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912267/6309):

```
git checkout -b tmp master
git merge -s ours mybranch           # ignoring all changes from mybranch
git checkout mybranch
git merge tmp                        # fast-forward to tmp HEAD
git branch -D tmp                    # deleting tmp
```