# Retrospectively build a release history in the master branch in git

Tags: git, merge, git-flow

I am trying retrospectively apply the principles of git flow to my repository.

I have all my releases tagged, and I would like to

1. Create a new master branch
2. Merge each tagged release into the new master branch as a squashed commit.

with the result being a master branch with a history containing only releases.

I tried to do the above, the first merge went as expected. And a diff confirmed that my master branch was identical to the tagged release. The second commit appeared to merge correctly, however a diff with the corresponding tagged release commit revealed many differences.

1. What could account for the tagged release merge resulting in a commit that was different?
2. How do I ensure the result of the merge is exactly the same as the tagged release commit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that surprising that when merging two release branches corresponding to different tags leads to a tree that is not an exact copy of that of one of the tags, because it is precisely a *merge* and the result depends on the history that leads to both tags.

So I guess that your question amounts to the need for command

```
git merge -s theirs branch-of-release
```

**which doesn't exist**, as explained in Git's [doc of git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-theirs):

> […] note that, unlike ours, there is no theirs merge strategy […]

Nevertheless, I found the following answer on SO that could be useful for your use case: [git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267).