# Make one Git branch exactly the same as another without merging

Tags: git

Consider the following Git graph

```
master:   A - B - C - D - E*
               \         /
feature:        X - Y - Z
```

I want to make a new commit in master, *E*, such that *E* precisely matches *Z*. In other words, any changes that may have been made in commits C and D are completely discarded. However, I would still like to retain the property that doing `git checkout HEAD~1` in master would checkout *D*.

Doing `git checkout master; git reset --hard feature` gets the working directory in the proper state (i.e., all tracked content precisely matches that of *Z*). However, is does not leave the history in the way that I intend.

Doing something like `git checkout feature -- .` *almost* works, but retains any files created in *B* or *C*, so it won't always precisely match the state of *Z*.

Doing something suggested in other responses to similar questions seems quite inefficient, as it involves several different checkouts and merges and is something I need to specifically avoid, as this operation will be done frequently and on rather large repositories.

It seems like years ago someone asked a similar question and got this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912267/927604

Part two of this question is: *Seriously?* Unless I'm missing something major, why is this not obvious to do?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you `git revert` C and D, and then merge feature?

Comment: Interesting, so do like `git revert A` (to be sure it's in a descendant branch of _feature_) and then `git merge feature`?

Comment: This is really a "why isn't there a `git merge -s theirs`" question. You linked one of them; the other that I recall is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours

Comment: My preferred method for doing this (not that I've actually ever needed or wanted to do this!) is in [Michael R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806926/1256452), but [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16526138/1256452) is good too.  Note that you can wrap either one into an alias, if you really need to do it repeatedly.

Comment: @torek I mention Michael's command in an alias in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741538/6309