# Git force merge dev branch to master branch (overwrite all local files)

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have an old, out-of-sync project code in the master branch. Several files have been deleted, added, re-written and thoroughly edited. I want to force merge stable latest code from development branch into master. I am trying to force merge, but still get merge conflicts.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
➜  project git:(development) git checkout master
➜  project git:(master) git pull
➜  project git:(master) git merge -s recursive -X theirs development

CONFLICT (modify/delete): vendors/popup/magnific-popup.css deleted in HEAD and modified in development. Version development of vendors/popup/magnific-popup.css left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): vendors/popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js deleted in HEAD and modified in development. Version development of vendors/popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): vendors/owl-carousel/assets/animated.css deleted in HEAD and modified in development. Version development of vendors/owl-carousel/assets/animated.css left in tree.

... several similar conflicts
```

I tried doing a `rm` of all files in my master branch

```
➜  project git:(master) git reset --hard HEAD
➜  project git:(master) rm -rf *
➜  project git:(master) git merge -s recursive -X theirs development
```

Still get the same conflicts. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Here is a graph for better understanding about what is going on. At some point, unrelated histories were also pushed.

[image]

Comment: If you want to avoid examining all the conflicts, do you just want to make the dev branch your new master?

Comment: Stop deleting files? Git is telling you there is a conflict because the files have been changed by multiple commits and it needs help figuring out which changes you want tot keep.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I want to keep the files from the latest commit.

Comment: @DeNovo That is one possible option. I dont want to lose the history on the existing master branch though.

Comment: Do you care about the state in master?

Comment: @evolutionxbox absolutely not. That is the reason why I kept doing `rm -rf`. But I care about master's history. Therefore not willing to delete master branch altogether.

Comment: True... Then I would reset master to point to development. Can you change master however you like? Is the branch shared with anyone else?

Comment: Yes, I can change master howsoever I like, since the previous developers left and I am the sole maintainer.

Comment: I tried `git reset --hard development` on master branch. However when I try to push, I got `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current...`  Doing `git pull` again gave me the merge conflicts.

Comment: Just rename the master branch something meaningful. A branch is just a pointer and master is just another branch

Comment: resetting master may leave the commit history unreachable and available for garbage collection. This is effectively deleting the master branch. You're just moving the branch ref called master to the development branch tip.

Comment: You’ll need to force push after a hard reset

Comment: @evolutionxbox tracking relationships are maintained with the branch ref, so force pushing doesn't save the commits left behind.

Comment: OP stated they don’t care about that history. If this is wrong, then the branch can be renamed to something else and master created at the tip of development.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the OP specifically said they do care about the history, which is why that will work, which is my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want this kind of merge at all.  I think what you want is a "theirs strategy" merge, which Git doesn't offer.  It can still be done: see [VonC's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912267/1256452).  But read on to be sure that this *is* what you want, before you use it.

---

There are two important things going on here, both sort-of captured by your command sequence:

> ```
> git checkout master
> git merge -s recursive -X theirs development
> ```

(I left out the step that didn't do anything).

The first is that most merges—including that from the default `-s recursive` merge strategy—work by finding a common starting point: a shared *merge base* commit.  To draw this as a rather simple case, consider the following commit graph:

```
          C--D--E   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--o--B
         \
          F--G--H   <-- development
```

Obviously your own graph will be much hairier, but in the end, this all works out the same: Git takes the *current commit*, as indicated by your current branch `master`, which is commit `E`, as one of the three inputs to the merge process.  Git takes the commit you *specify*, in this case commit `H` because `development` is the one you said to look at, as the second of the three inputs to the merge process.

The *third* input is computed from the graph.  We start at each of the two tip commits and begin walking backwards, the way Git always does.  Commit `E` leads back to `D`, which leads to `C` and then to `B`.  Meanwhile commit `H` leads to `G` to `F` to `B`.  Commit `B` is on *both* branches, and it is, in graph terms, the *lowest common ancestor*.<sup>1</sup>  (Informally, it's the one closest to both branch tips.  "Closest" breaks down in complex graphs, but for simple ones like this, that's what lowest common ancestor means.)  That makes it the best shared commit, and hence the merge base.

What happens now is pretty simple in general terms, but gets sticky in some details.  Git starts with the *merge base* commit in terms of "desired result".  That is, the contents Git starts with are those from the snapshot in commit `B`.  To these contents, Git needs to apply the *combination* of any changes that *you* made and any changes that *they* made.  So Git needs to run two `git diff` commands:

- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-B hash-of-E`: what we changed on `master`
- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-B hash-of-H`: what they changed on `development`

If the merge base is close to both tips, as it is here, probably each of these two diffs doesn't show all that much.  Combining the two sets of changes will be easy and straightforward.  If we changed line 12 of `README.md`, and they didn't touch `README.md` at all, Git takes our change, giving our version of `README.md` to go in the new merge commit.  If they touched a different line of `README.md`, Git puts our two changes together: both get applied to `B:README.md` to produce the `README.md` for the new commit.  This process repeats for all the files.

If we and they both touched the *same* line(s) of the same files, though, Git would normally declare a merge conflict and stop, leaving us to clean up the mess.  That's where the `-X theirs` option comes in: this is an *eXtended option*, passed on to the `-s` strategy.<sup>2</sup>  In this case, the `recursive` strategy treats the `theirs` extended-option as meaning: *in the case of a conflict, throw away my change and use theirs*.

Note that if there *isn't* a conflict, Git will use *our* change!  Sometimes that's what we want.  If it *is* what we want, `-X theirs` is the right idea.  If it's *not* what we want, `-X theirs` is the wrong idea.  So that's where you need to decide: do we use `-X theirs`, or do we use a `-s theirs` that we have to construct as in VonC's answer?

---

<sup>1</sup>It's the *lowest* common ancestor because computer scientists draw their trees upside down:

```
     A
     |
     B
   /   \
  C     D
 / \     \
E   F     G
```

The common ancestors of E and F here are C, B, and A, but C is the *lowest* one.  The common ancestors of F and G are B and A; B is lowest.  Git's commit graph is a directed acyclic graph or DAG, rather than a tree, so "LCA" is not as simple as it is in a tree, and there can be multiple LCAs (or no LCA at all) given two nodes in a graph.  Git handles all this sensibly, for some definition of sensible.

<sup>2</sup>Git calls `-X` a *strategy option*, but that sounds exactly like the `-s strategy` argument.  It's literally an option to the strategy, hence Git's poorly-chosen name.  I think *eXtended option* is a better name, in part because it explains the `-X`.

---

#### If you don't want `-X theirs`: see the other answer I linked

There's not much more to say: `-s theirs` was once a Git merge strategy.  It isn't any more.  You can still synthesize it, in any number of ways.  My favorite is actually the plumbing command variety in [Michal Soltys' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12301108/1256452).

#### If you do want `-X theirs`: why is it complaining of conflicts?

I mentioned above that the merge process—the *to merge* part of `git merge`—is "pretty simple ... but gets sticky in some details."  You have just hit one of those details.

The massive `git diff`s that Git gets from diffing the merge base it found, vs each of the two tip commits you have specified, has a lot of cases of files that were *completely deleted* by one side, but *modified* by the other side:

```
...--B--o--o--...--o--o   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       o--o--...--o--o   <-- development
```

Somewhere in that massive chain of anonymous `o` commits along the top, "we" (base vs master) *deleted* some file.  "They" (base vs development) *changed* that file.  Git doesn't know how to combine "deleted" with "changed".

I call these *high level* conflicts, because they are changes to the very nature or existence of a file, rather than to the individual lines within a file.  Well, I also call it that because Git itself calls the part of the code that combines individual lines the "low level merge driver", so these must be the opposite, *high* level.  These kinds of conflicts—whether add/add, modify/delete, rename/delete, or what—*always* cause a `-s recursive` `git merge` to stop and let you fix up the mess.  The extended options are only given to the *low* level merge *driver* invoked by the strategy.

In fact, the only strategy that *doesn't* stop is the `-s ours` strategy.  When you use the `-s ours` strategy, that one *totally ignores* what's in "their" commit.  Git doesn't even bother looking at the merge base at all—it just uses what's in *our* commit as the merge result.

Of course, `-s ours` takes *ours*.  You wanted something that took *theirs*, at least for this particular case, maybe for all cases.  But if you really *don't* want the equivalent of `-s theirs`, but rather `-X theirs` with taking their entire file in these cases, you're stuck with resolving each of these conflicts after-the-fact.

You *can* do it with a script (which you must write yourself).  That's a little tricky though.  The trick is to use `git ls-files --stage`: you'll see that, for each file for which Git complained:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): vendors/popup/magnific-popup.css deleted in HEAD and modified in development. Version development of vendors/popup/magnific-popup.css left in tree.
```

Git will have an entry at stage #1 for the name (`vendors/popup/magnific-popup.css`), and another entry at stage #3 (theirs), but no entry at stage #2 (ours).  To resolve this, use `git add` to write the stage-3 entry from the work-tree into the index at stage zero: `git add` will remove the stage 1 and 3 copies.  You can just collect up all such file names and pass them all to `git add`.

Comment: This was pretty detailed. You rightly mentioned "... files that were completely deleted by one side, but modified by the other side...". This is indeed my use case. Since I wasn't well versed with the script, I had to manually merge each file (over 150 of them) but finally it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This will just set `master` to be the same as your `development` branch - anything in master committed after the last merge of `development` will be lost.

`git checkout -B master development`

Answer (score 0):

A branch is just a pointer, and `master` is just another branch. If you haven't been merging changes as you go and `dev` represents the current stable state of the project, one option that would save you from going through all the conflicts would be:

```
git branch -m master <new-name>
git branch -m dev master
```

There may be a need to tweak tracking relationships, depending on how you have any remotes set up.