# How to sync two branches, without doing a new commit, which is having merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have to sync two branches, but it is having merge conflicts.
There is a lot merge conflicts are there. So resolving all is not possible.
Is there any other way, so we can sync?

There is 2 branch
**release/uat**,
**release/preprod**
need to sync this two, but not possible to do, manually resolve conflicts.

Comment: How did you come to have these two branches in this state? It’s not clear what you are asking but `How to sync two branches, without doing a new commit` this is impossible. `So resolving all is not possible` I doubt that’s true since that is “the way” -  but why not? Please edit the question to add specific details, questions that are just a description are generally too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need by "syncing" those two branches.

Conflicts means concurrent development, but if you need `branchB` to reflect `branchA` (instead of merging `branchA` into `branchB` and resolving all conflict, you can make `branchB` like `branchA`.

See for instance "[git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912267/6309)"

```bash
git switch -c tmp branchA
git merge -s ours branchB       # ignoring all changes from branchB
git checkout branchB
git merge tmp                   # fast-forward to tmp HEAD
git branch -D tmp               # deleting tmp
```

Anything else would mean resolving conflicts.

Comment: Curious to see if your spideysense guessed right here :). Merging UAT into preproduction and (likely) ignoring patches applied in UAT sounds like a pretty dangerous thing to do.

Comment: @AD7six Agreed. But for me, "not resolving merge conflict" means only one thing: make one branch like the other.