# How to merge the master branch commits to feature branch after revoking all the feature branch related commits?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-branch

I have a scenario where there is a master branch, and a feature branch is cut from the master branch.

1. Master branch
2. Feature branch

all our custom changes to the code are committed to the *feature* branch for custom configs testing. Meanwhile there will be many commits happening to the *Master* branch in parallel by other developers.

So after a week or two the I want to get all the new changes from the *master* branch and git rid of all the commits I made in the *Feature* branch. i,e want to get my *feature* branch in sync with latest *master* without my commits.

I got solution to get the *master* commits to my *feature* branch but not very clear solution to get rid of my commits from my *feature* branch.

My end goal is to sync my feature branch every couple of weeks with *master* branch and remove all my commits as well, so my *feature* branch is same as the *master*.

This can be done simply by deleting the feature branch and creating a new one from master, but we do not have the power to create/delete new branch, so we need to live with a single feature branch for all our custom testing.

Answer (score 2):

> we do not have the power to create/delete new branch

If you can force push, though, there is the simple option of resetting your feature branch:

```bash
git switch master
git pull
git switch -C feature master
git push --force
```

If not, pick one option from "[git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912267/6309)".

For instance:

```bash
git switch -c tmp master
git merge -s ours feature       # ignoring all changes from feature
git checkout feature
git merge tmp                   # fast-forward to tmp HEAD
git branch -D tmp               # deleting tmp
```