# How to automatically resolve a Git conflict by taking the version in the current branch?

Tags: git, merge, automation, conflict

Let's suppose that I get a merge conflict on `foo/bar.txt` when running this:

```
$ git checkout A
$ git merge B
```

I'd like to automatically resolve the conflict by taking `foo/bar.txt` from branch A. (I know what I'm doing, and I do need this. The version in branch B is wrong, and I don't care about losing changes in the working tree in this case.) It seems that I can do it by running these commands:

```
$ git reset    foo/bar.txt
$ git checkout foo/bar.txt
```

Is there a simpler, single-command solution?

Unfortunately these commands change `foo/bar.txt` even if there is no conflict, and I don't want that. If there is no conflict, I want want to keep `foo/bar.txt` in whatever state `git merge B` has left it.

So I need a Unix shell command, which would detect if there is a conflict in `foo/bar.txt`, and if there is, it would resolve the conflict by taking the version of `foo/bar.txt` from the current branch. It wouldn't do anything else, i.e. it wouldn't modify other files, it wouldn't commit the changes, and it wouldn't change `foo/bar.txt` if there is no conflict in that file.

Comment: Remote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528659/git-automatic-conflict-resolution

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to do it as a one-off, the single-line command is:

```
$ git checkout --ours foo/bar.txt  # <-- resets it only if the merge found conflicts in this file
$ git checkout HEAD -- foo/bar.txt # <-- resets it to that specific version no matter what
```

To configure git's merge to permanently ignore all upstream changes to a locally-changed file:

```
$ git config merge.pin.driver true
$ echo foo/bar.txt merge=pin >> .git/info/attributes
```

(`true` above is just the unix `true` command, its success says it made the local version look right, in this case by doing nothing to it.  You can of course get more sophisticated with your merge commands.)

I think you don't want `merge --strategy=ours` or `--strategy-option=ours`, those apply to entire merges.

Answer (score 30):

You can specify the merge strategy *option* `ours` to the `recursive` (the default) merge strategy. It will perform a normal merge, but in case of conflicting hunks, it will choose the version of the current branch (i.e. ours).

```
git checkout A
git merge -X ours B
```

---

Note that this is very different from `-s ours`, which selects a different merge strategy. Doing so would throw away *all* changes of the other branch and only keep our version. Refer to [How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/how-do-i-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch-in-git) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for this additional information. Unfortunately it doesn't answer my question, because the `git merge B` command (and possibly many other uncommitted filesystem changes) has already been run.

Comment: If you have already run the merge command, then you must use the `reset && checkout` method.

Comment: The reset+checkout method is not an answer to my question either, because it's not a no-op if there is no conflict (see the question for details).

Comment: @pts: yeah, but I didn't say you have to do it unconditionally. And it's not a no-op, because there might be unconflicting changes which get merged just fine by Git's automatic conflict resolution.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout to target branch and merge with master and automatically can resolve with **theirs** conflict

```
git merge -X theirs master
```

Comment: Isn't this doing exactly the opposite of what the question wants?