# How to merge two sequential git repositories

Tags: git

I have a rather unique situation:

- I have a repository called Project1 that I worked on for a few
  months.
- A year later, I created the repository Project1_Again that
  took off where Project1 left off.
- Now, I would like the revision history to be continuous, so I would like them merged together, as if that new repository had never been created.

Is this possible?

To clarify:

Repo: Project1

- rev1: main.cpp has contents "h"
- rev2: main.cpp has contents "hello"
- rev3: main.cpp has contents "hello world"

Repo: Project1_Again

- rev1: main.cpp has contents "hello world"
- rev2: main.cpp has contents "hello world again"

My goal is to get Project1's revision history into Project1_Again:

Repo: Project1_Again

- rev1: main.cpp has contents "h"
- rev2: main.cpp has contents "hello"
- rev3: main.cpp has contents "hello world"
- rev4: main.cpp has contents "hello world again"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories?rq=1

Comment: This might work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/350351

Comment: Did you `git clone` the second project from the first, or did you just add files from the last commit of the 1st project?

Comment: @Daenyth: thanks--I'll check those both out.

Comment: @Cupcake: I merely copied the files--did not clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `project1` chronologically before `project2`:

```
cd project1
git checkout --orphan merging_project2
git rm -rf .
git pull protocol://project2_address/ master
git merge -Xours master
```

Comment: Thank you.  But this doesn't seem to completely work, as when I merge, it states that I have merge conflicts.  I wouldn't expect merge conflicts, as the changes from project2 (in your example) should have all come before project1, and thus shouldn't conflict. Am I just missing something?

Comment: If you have the same files in both projects you will have conflicts, even if they have the same content. It's the situation when you have added a file on a branch and then (chronologically later) a file of the same name on second branch. Git concludes that you are adding a file that already exists. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182259/how-to-automatically-resolve-a-git-conflict-by-taking-the-version-in-the-current) describes how you can automate merge process, but my advice is: try to resolve conflicts yourself.

Comment: I really appreciate your responses, but I think I haven't been clear enough in my question. I'll make it more explicit.

Comment: OK, my bad. Didn't catch that first project was abandoned. `git merge -Xours master` should do the trick. There should be no conflicts.

Comment: This did not work for me on a recent attempt, perhaps due to unrelated histories. Instead, `git replace --graft` worked, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49779160/82216).